# How do I theme repeating dates output field?

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

I currently have a calendar of events and each event has multiple repeating dates. Now when i display them it shows all those repeating dates in a long list. How would i theme this to show only if there are more than 3 dates to display":

**Has multiple dates in the coming month**

I was thinking of doing this via tpl's, but what should i name my tpl as to override this output?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question can you re-word it?

Comment: What modules are you using for this?

Comment: Where it says event date. i want it to show only "Has multiple dates" instead of showing that long list. as you can see its not exactly a pleasant look with all those dates listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new custom Formatter for this.
Some proposed solutions are listed below (with an order of importance):

- Use [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) function and alter values on node display
- Use the [Custom_Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module
- Use functions from the [Field Formatter API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7)
- Use the [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) template of course with an overwritten file name.

...

You can use [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) to inspect your field structure.

Comment: No answer for almost a week and then we both answer within 60 seconds of each other!

Comment: @FelixEve I came here from a tweet...

Answer (score 0):

Using [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) seems to do the trick. You can either put this in your themes template.php or in a custom module.

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

    $most_repeating_dates_to_show = 5; // set limit of how many repeating dates is acceptable to show

    if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_date') { // Put your actual field name where it says "field_date"

        $num_repeats = count($variables['items']); // get count of how many repeating dates there are

        if($num_repeats > $most_repeating_dates_to_show) {

            $nid = $variables['element']['#object']->nid; // get the nid of the parent node

            // set the title of the link to show how many repeating dates there are
            $link_options = array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'title' => t('See all :num repeating dates', array(':num' => $num_repeats))
                )
            );

            $link = l('Has multiple dates', 'node/'.$nid.'/repeats', $link_options);

            $variables['items'] = array(0 => array('#markup' => $link)); // here we overwrite the whole array of items so only our link will show

        }

    }

}
```

I've added a bit of extra functionality turning your text "Has multiple dates" into a link that links to the full list of repeating dates.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was modify hook_date_display_single() as seen below. I had it detect todays date then compare it to the repeating dates and if they are past todays date grey it out and do a strikethrough. I also had it remove the YEAR using preg_replace(). I did that so it wouldn't show up for that specific date format. Its a quick and dirty fix, but obviously it can be polished up.

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for a date element formatted as a single date.
 */
function THEMENAME_date_display_single($variables) {
  $date = $variables['date'];
  $noyr_date = preg_replace('/\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/', '', $variables['date']);
  $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

if(((time()-(60*60*24)) > strtotime($date)) && (strtotime($date) != 0)) {
  // Wrap the result with the attributes.
  return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '><del>' . $noyr_date . $timezone . '</del></span>';
} else {
  return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $noyr_date . $timezone . '</span>';
}
}
```

The output of that looks like this as compared to the original on the original question:

[image]